# SQL Server: inner join running total

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm doing some work on a SQL Server 2008 database (before partition) and trying to get my head running totals using inner joins. I've followed a few online tutorials but I can't get the desired results.

This is the underlying data...

```
 Compdate   count
 ------------------
 2          198
 3           29
 4           22
 5           27
 6           31
 9           18
 10          16
 11          22
 12          26
 etc...
```

and I need to add a running total column.

This is the query I've created so far...

```
select 
    t1.Compdate,
    t1.count,
    Sum(t2.count) as 'Total'
from 
    DB_KpiTr_Remo_CumComp_TV t1
inner join 
    (select count, compdate 
     from DB_KpiTr_Remo_CumComp_TV 
     where Month like 'l%') t2 on t1.Count >= t2.Count
                               and t1.Compdate = t2.Compdate
where 
    t1.Month like 'l%'
group by 
    t1.Compdate, t1.count
order by  
    t1.Compdate

select Compdate, count
from DB_KpiTr_Remo_CumComp_TV t1
```

But all I'm getting back is the exact same numbers in my total column...

```
Compdate    count   Total
-------------------------
2           198     198
3            29      29
4            22      22
etc...
```

I've tried several combinations of joins and I get several combinations of results but not the one I'm looking for - what am I missing here?

Comment: Left justified SQL is very hard to read, and to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
select u.*, u2.running_count
from underlying u outer apply
     (select sum(u2.count) as running_count
      from underlying u2
      where u2.compdate <= u.compdate
     ) u2
```